# Conversion from type 'Range' to type 'String' is not valid

Tags: vb.net, excel

```
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = int_start To 1 Step -1
        If InStr(rng_delete.Cells(i), "VALUE") > 0 Then
            rng_delete.Cells(i).EntireRow.Delete()
        End If
    Next i
```

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll.
>   Additional information: Conversion from type 'Range' to type 'String' is not valid.

Comment: This is not VBA, is it? The error suggests, this is more VB.Net.

Comment: If rng_delete is of type `Range` as the error message suggests, you should use `rng_delete.Cells(i).Value.ToString()` in your if statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify which property of the cell you are passing to InStr (usually either .Value or .Text).

```
If InStr(rng_delete.Cells(i).Text, "VALUE") > 0 Then
```